# In coming emails not updating issue fields in Redmine

Tags: rake, redmine, rakefile

I am trying to set up Redmine so that it can receive emails to create tickets .
The command I use to fetch emails is

```
rake --trace redmine:email:receive_pop3 RAILS_ENV="production" host=my.mail.server port=110 username=born@mydomain.com password=***** project=foobar
```

email contents are like

```
Project: foobar
Tracker: Bugz
Status: New
Priority: Normal
```

On receiving this email redmine created a new ticket . However files Tracker,Status and Priority is not getting updated with the values from email . Instead the entire email body is getting updated in Description field of the new ticket. 
Are my emails not in the correct format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine only allows setting attributes from the mail body which are explicitly enumerated on the command line.

You can specify which attributes are allowed to be set using the @allow_override@ argument to the rake task similar to this:

```
rake redmine:email:receive_pop3 RAILS_ENV="production" ... allow_override=project,tracker,status,priority
```

Please see the documentation at http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails#Issue-attributes for details.